# Should citations be used before or after equations?

Tags: equations, citing, best-practices

Should I put citations before or after equations?

For example: the following sequence

```
\citep{----}
\begin{equation}
--------
\end{equation}
```

or the following sequence

```
\begin{equation}
--------
\end{equation}
\citep{----}
```

Comment: Please do not use excessive highlighting. Also notice that code should be marked as such. (I edited that for you.) As for your question, I don't see why the order would matter. If you have a specific case, where you think it does, please provide more context.

Comment: If this is a matter of style, maybe your university and/or supervisor (in case of thesis) can have specific policies... In that case, by the way, this might not be a question about TeX and co.

Comment: This looks like a candidate to be migrated to the academic StackExchange site: it's as @scannerdarkly says about style, aand not really about TeX (unless you want some form of selectable style based on your code, which is then on-topic).

Comment: if the citation is placed after the equation, there's no guarantee it will be set on the same page; in fact, *after* equations is generally considered (by tex) to be a good place to break a page. but it's usually "bad style" to break a page just before an equation, so there's a much better chance a preceding citation will end up on the same page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a matter of convention, used in most reputed journals, the citations are used before equation environment.  That is the first method is better. Moreover, this makes the citation more visible than the second method. Also in the second method, if numbered citations are used, it may get confused with the equation itself.

As someone has already mentioned this is a question for academia.se and may be migrated or cross posted.